# Single quote escaping in SQL Server query - using parameterised value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Below is my trimmed down C#:

```
thisConnection.Open();
string commandtext = "Insert into Table (Comments)values('@Comments')";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandtext, thisConnection);
command.Parameters.Add("@Comments", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Comments;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
thisConnection.Close();
```

I can enter almost anything, with certain special characters being stripped out before being entered into the database, which is fine by me, by even just one single quote will throw a spanner in the works. I've tried adding `.Replace("'","''");` to the `Comments` variable but this doesn't change anything, and I though using parameters should prevent this anyway.

I know questions like this have been asked a lot, but everywhere just points at "use parameters!"

---

**Edit**: Seeing as four people have said the same thing, I'm replying to it all here.
I have removed the single quotes around `@Comments`, but the issue is the exact same. Any input with single quotes isn't entered to the database at all.

I have added `.replace(/'/g,"''")` before we get here with javascript, and this is working, but I don't see why I should have to.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Perhaps you simplified your code for this question, but you've got a `commandtext` variable somewhere that you pass to the `SqlCommand` constructor, and you then immediately override the `CommandText` property of the command, so `commandtext` is effectively unused.

Comment: @hvd you're absolutely right it's unused above. I've stopped overriding it. I'll change the code above.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the single quotes.

```
command.CommandText = "Insert into Table (Comments)values(@Comments)";
```

Ok, reading around a little after the comment of `hvd`, i saw that the way this works is by executing `sp_executesql`.

A way to get around this could be the following:

```
thisConnection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandtext, thisConnection);
command.CommandText = "Insert into Table (Comments)values(@Comments)";
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@Comments";
param.Value         = Comments;
command.Parameters.Add(param);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
thisConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Noted, and updated my code, but it didn't change anything. See edit.

Comment: @dudledok You may check my edit and let me know if it is clear.

Comment: -1: that isn't how parameters work at all. They don't work by textual replacement.

Comment: @hvd Where did i say that it will be a textual replacement? I am just saying how this is interpreted in SQL.

Comment: As you can see from my original post, I tried replacing single quotes with two single quotes in the codebehind and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @hvd By the way, thanks for at least giving a reason for downvoting. Much better than just downvoting. :)

Comment: @jyparask You said "This effectively ends the string value in This is my friend so the rest is not interpreted by SQL and will throw an error.", and sorry, but that is completely wrong. Parameters don't work like that.

Comment: @jyparask A minimal testcase is `using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) using (var command = new SqlCommand("select @p", connection)) { command.Parameters.Add("@p", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "'''"; connection.Open(); result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); }`, you'll see that `result` is property assigned `"'''"`.

Comment: @jyparask Downvote reverted after your edit, by the way. :) I don't see anything wrong in your edited version (other than that I think that since you don't specify the parameter type, it'll implicitly be NVarChar instead of VarChar), but it shouldn't behave any differently from what the OP already has.

Comment: @hvd A constructive comment is always useful. It is nice that some times attempting to answer a question leads you to make things clearer... Again thanks.

Comment: Your code is now the same, you've just split the building of the parameter over multiple lines.

Comment: @dudledok I am afraid that it works when i test it. Can you provide an input that fails and what exactly is the error that you get?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to escape single quotes when using parameters. 
Assuming that `Comments` is type `String` then just do:

```
command.CommandText = "Insert into Table (Comments)values(@Comments)";
command.Parameters.Add("@Comments", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as shown:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table (Comments) VALUES(@Comments)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Insert into Table (Comments)values('@Comments')";
```

should be

```
"Insert into Table (Comments)values(@Comments)"; <-- no single quotes
```

The reason people are suggesting you use `parameters` is to avoid [`SQL injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Take a look at [`Bobby Tables`](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something like this and I didn't get any exception but it may not safe for SQL injection.

```
Comments.Replace("'", $"{(char)39}");
```